# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0 } \frac{x}{\sin{\pi(x+2)}}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I divided the limit by the product of the two limits.

The first limit is found, but how to calculate second:
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0 } \frac{x}{\sin{\pi(x+2)}}$

Comment: use the periodicity of the sin function: $\sin(a+2\pi)=\sin(a)$

Comment: Thank you, I need understand why $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is $1$...

Comment: @divisor. the expansion of $sin(x)$ is $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}...$. Factor out x and, you get - $x[1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!}...]$. In the parantheses, set all terms except the $1$ to zero as $x$ tends to zero. The $x$ is now divided out by the $x$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin\pi(x+2)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin(\pi x+2\pi)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin\pi x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}1^{-1}=\frac{1}{\pi}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @divisor very much welcome

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\sin(\pi(x+2))=\sin(x\pi+2\pi)$$
$$=\sin(x\pi )$$

$$\lim_{X\to 0}\frac{X}{\sin(X)}=1$$

Comment: I know that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, why $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is $1$ too?

Comment: L'Hopital for example.

Comment: Sorry, L'Hopital rule is unavailable, I needed $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}\right)^{-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Assume we already know $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 \frac{x}{sinx}}=1$.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 \frac{x}{sin{\pi (x+2)}}} 
= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{sin{\pi x}}
= \lim_{\pi x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\pi x}{sin{\pi x}} \cdot \frac{1}{\pi}
= \frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{u}{sinu}
= \frac{1}{\pi}$

As for $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 \frac{x}{sinx}}=1$, it needs another proof.

Comment: I know that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, why $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is $1$ too?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}\right)^{-1}$

Comment: Do you mean we already know $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sinx}{x}=1$, why $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{sinx} = 1$? The limit has its multiplication property and division property.

Comment: Like that, $1=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sinx}{x} \frac{x}{sinx} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sinx}{x} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{sinx} = 1 \cdot \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{sinx}$. Maybe it is not serious.

Comment: Sorry, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sinx}{x} \frac{x}{sinx}$ it's my stupidity...

Comment: I would like to increase more, but I can increase only once :(

Answer (score 1):

with the help of the rules of L'Hospital we obtain
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sin(\pi(x+2))}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{\pi\cos(\pi(x+2))}=...$$

Comment: you are missing a $\pi$ when you derivate $\sin$

Comment: L'Hopital rule is unavailable...